# XSLT - Formatting XML to plain text whith a specific length

Tags: xml, xslt, text, formatting

My question is regarding convert an XML through XSLT into a plain text and give an specífic length on each XML tag converted.

For instance:

**XML Input**

```
<Request>
        <Products>
                <WEBVersion>5</WEBVersion>
                <Subscriber>
                    <INNERCODE>0001</INNERCODE>
                    <INITIALS>DK</INITIALS>
                    <CODE>1555888991</CODE>
                    <FIRSTNAME>DAVE</FIRSTNAME>
                    <LASTNAME>KRUVCZEC</LASTNAME>
                </Subscriber>
         </Products>
</Request>
```

**The tags:**

- WEBVersion has 1 character
- INNERCODE has 4 characters
- INITIALS has 3 characters
- CODE has 20 characters
- FIRSTNAME has 20 characters
- LASTNAME has 20 characters

**The wanted output:**

```
50001 DK           1555888991                DAVE            KRUVCZEC
```

Comment: I believe that if you search for [XSLT] fixed width (or fixed length), you will find some useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your clue @michael.hor257k with your tags I've found a solution.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
        <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:variable name="some_spaces" select="'                                                                  '" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Request/Products" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Request/Products">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="WEBVersion">
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(2-1)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="INNERCODE">
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(7-3)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
..
..
..
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template  match="node()" mode ="format">
            <xsl:param name="width" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(text(),$some_spaces ), 1, $width+1)"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template  match="node()" mode="format_date">
            <xsl:param name="width" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(translate(text(),'/',''),$some_spaces ), 1, $width+1)"/>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```